# Comparing user input from a list of words

Tags: python, python-3.x, spyder

So I am writing a program that will take in user input and then will take the user input and compare it to a set list and then tell me how many words from the user input are in the given list.

For Example:

```py
list = ['I','like','apples']    # set list

user_in = input('Say a phrase:')

# the user types: I eat apples.
#
# then the code will count and total the similar words 
#  in the list from the user input.
```

I've gotten close with this, I know I might have to convert the user input into a list itself. just need help comparing and counting matching words.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to provide the code you tried. Also StackOverflow has a policy about [homework questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18242/what-is-the-policy-here-on-homework)

Answer (score 1):

```
len([word for word in user_in if word in list])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

`similarWords=0                  #initialize a counter
for word in user_in.split():
    if word in list:            #check and compare if word is in set list
        similarWords+=1         #increase counter by 1 every time a word matches`

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can split your user input with user_in.split(' ').
Then compare each word in the user_in_list with a word in the check list and increase the counter when this is the case:

```
list = ['I','like','apples'] # set list

user_in = input('Say a phrase:')

ui = user_in.split(' ')

count = 0
for word in ui:
    if word in list:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
l1 = ['I','like','apples']    # set list
user = input('Say a phrase:')
a=user.split(' ')
k=0
print(a)
for i in l1:
    if i in l1:
        k+=1
print("similar words:",k)
```

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

By using the function [split()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) you can split the given phrase into words.
And it is better to use a ui.lower() or ui.upper() to avoid case sensitivity

```
    li = ['i', 'like', 'apples']    #initial list
    ui = input('say a phrase')      #taking input from user
    ui = ui.lower()                 #converting string into lowercase
    ui_list = ui.split()            #converting phrase into list containing words
    count = 0
    for word in ui_list:
    if word in li:
        print(word)
        count += 1
    print(count)                     #printing matched words
```